# How do I dynamically build a search block in sunspot?

Tags: sunspot, sunspot-rails

I am converting a Rails app from using acts_as_solr to sunspot.

The app uses the field search capability in solr that was exposed in acts_as_solr. You could give it a query string like this:

```
title:"The thing to search"
```

and it would search for that string in the title field.

In converting to sunspot I am parsing out field specific portions of the query string and I need to dynamically generate the search block. Something like this:

```
Sunspot.search(table_clazz) do
  keywords(first_string, :fields => :title)
  keywords(second_string, :fields => :description)

  ...
  paginate(:page => page, :per_page => per_page)      
end
```

This is complicated by also needing to do duration (seconds, integer) ranges and negation if the query requires it.

On the current system users can search for something in the title, excluding records with something else in another field and scoping by duration.

In a nutshell, how do I generate these blocks dynamically?

Comment: Just a thought : can we create a block in ruby dynamically and pass it to the search function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this myself. The solution I used was to compiled the required scopes as strings, concatenate them, and then eval them inside the search block.

This required a separate query builder library that interrogates the solr indexes to ensure that a scope is not created for a non existent index field.

The code is very specific to my project, and too long to post in full, but this is what I do:

**1. Split the search terms**

this gives me an array of the terms or terms plus fields:

`['field:term', 'non field terms']`

**2. This is passed to the query builder.**

The builder converts the array to scopes, based on what indexes are available. This method is an example that takes the model class, field and value and returns the scope if the field is indexed.

```
def convert_text_query_to_search_scope(model_clazz, field, value)
  if field_is_indexed?(model_clazz, field)
    escaped_value = value.gsub(/'/, "\\\\'")
    "keywords('#{escaped_value}', :fields => [:#{field}])"
  else
    ""
  end
end
```

**3. Join all the scopes**

The generated scopes are joined `join("\n")` and that is `eval`ed.

This approach allows the user to selected the models they want to search, and optionally to do field specific searching. The system will then only search the models with any specified fields (or common fields), ignoring the rest.

The method to check if the field is indexed is:

```
# based on http://blog.locomotivellc.com/post/6321969631/sunspot-introspection
def field_is_indexed?(model_clazz, field)
  # first part returns an array of all indexed fields - text and other types - plus ':class'
  Sunspot::Setup.for(model_clazz).all_field_factories.map(&:name).include?(field.to_sym)
end
```

And if anyone needs it, a check for sortability:

```
def field_is_sortable?(classes_to_check, field)
  if field.present?
    classes_to_check.each do |table_clazz|
      return false if ! Sunspot::Setup.for(table_clazz).field_factories.map(&:name).include?(field.to_sym)
    end
    return true
  end
  false
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I recently did this kind of thing using `instance_eval` to evaluate procs (created elsewhere) in the context of the Sunspot search block.

The advantage is that these procs can be created anywhere in your application yet **you can write them with the same syntax as if you were inside a sunspot search block**.

Here's a quick example to get you started for your particular case:

```
def build_sunspot_query(conditions)
  condition_procs = conditions.map{|c| build_condition c}

  Sunspot.search(table_clazz) do
    condition_procs.each{|c| instance_eval &c}

    paginate(:page => page, :per_page => per_page)
  end
end

def build_condition(condition)
  Proc.new do
    # write this code as if it was inside the sunspot search block

    keywords condition['words'], :fields => condition[:field].to_sym
  end
end

conditions = [{words: "tasty pizza", field: "title"},
              {words: "cheap",       field: "description"}]

build_sunspot_query conditions
```

By the way, if you need to, you can even instance_eval a proc inside of another proc (in my case I composed arbitrarily-nested 'and'/'or' conditions).

Comment: Thanks, that is really useful. How do you test the builder?

Comment: @RichardHulse - Each test case could construct a list of conditions and pass it to the query builder, then check that the results are as expected (given a known set of data in the testing database)... Is that the kind of thing you meant?

Comment: I was thinking more isolated that that - just testing the correct procs are compiled, but I spose I just answered my own question!

Answer (score 2):

Sunspot provides a method called Sunspot.new_search which lets you build the search conditions incrementally and execute it on demand.

An example provided by the [Sunspot's source code](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot/lib/sunspot.rb):

```
search = Sunspot.new_search do
  with(:blog_id, 1)
end
search.build do
  keywords('some keywords')
end
search.build do
  order_by(:published_at, :desc)
end
search.execute

# This is equivalent to:
Sunspot.search do
  with(:blog_id, 1)
  keywords('some keywords')
  order_by(:published_at, :desc)
end
```

With this flexibility, you should be able to build your query dynamically. Also, you can extract common conditions to a method, like so:

```
def blog_facets
  lambda { |s|
    s.facet(:published_year)
    s.facet(:author)
  }
end

search = Sunspot.new_search(Blog)
search.build(&blog_facets)
search.execute
```